# Hadoop Single Node Cluster - Process Not Running

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have this project to do with Hadoop and I have installed Hadoop just as described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform 
I'm trying to run the same map-reduce job **Recipe.java** on the dataset **recipeitems-latest.json**

I have created a .jar file from this Recipe.java code, and I've started YARN and DFS. I have also created the directory /in and copied recipeitems-latest.json to it.

Now, I start the job by calling:

```
hadoop jar c:\Hwork\Recipe.jar Recipe /in /out
```

The job starts, says running but no progress is made as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSifC.png 

I tried tracking the job too by clicking on given link, its status is accepted but the progress bar shows nothing. 

I have started using Hadoop only 1 day back and I really don't know what is going wrong. Why is there no progress in the job I started?

Comment: "URL to track the job". Go find the logs there

Comment: Also, Hadoop 2.7 is the current stable release. That link is rather old

Comment: I checked them logs, and the processes show no progress. Tracking URL is unassigned

Comment: That might indicate the ResourceManager is unable to assign an application master. Have you started all the YARN services?

Comment: I gave start-yarn are there any other services to be started?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't mean things run successfully. Are you able to run `jps` command? That should say what processes are running

Comment: I just figured out YARN nodemanager is not running. It says The system cannot find the batch label specified - nodemanager

Comment: jps command runs C:\hadoop-2.3.0\sbin>jps
5212 ResourceManager
1016 NameNode
7820 Program
1536 DataNode
13572 Jps

Comment: Sounds like the issue. I've never tried Hadoop on Windows, but seems like the cmd scripts are not quite right. Are you required to use Hadoop/mapreduce? Apache Spark has built in support for JSON handling, and doesn't require Hadoop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. Apparently EOL characters in \sbin\start-yarn must be changed (as well as in \bin\hadoop.cmd) from '\n' to '\r\n' and it worked like a charm!